# JavaFX FXML Slider to return integers instead of Doubles

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am trying to get integers from sliders so that I can pass the result to a class constructor needing integers, not doubles. So just for testing, from my controller I call:

```
@FXML
public void handleStartButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    System.out.println((int) worldSizeXSlider.getValue());
}
```

and it does not print an integer. it throws an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at simulationx.MainController.handleStartButtonAction(MainController.java:37)
... 60 more
```

here is the xfml tag in a gridpane

```
<Slider fx:id="WorldSizeXSlider" min="0" max="100"
        value="50"
        GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
```

and here is the initialization in my controller:
    public class MainController implements Initializable {

```
@FXML
private Label worldSizeXLabel;
private Label worldSizeYLabel;
private Slider worldSizeXSlider;
```

Comment: If it is throwing a `NullPointerException`, `worldSizeXSlider` is null or `getValue` is returning null. Try printing those out first individually before you try the `int` cast.

Comment: Ok so the problem is with getValue.
            codeSystem.out.println(worldSizeXSlider.getValue());
prints the same error.

Comment: You haven't established that `worldSizeXSlider` is not `null`. What happens if you do `System.out.println(worldSizeXSlider);`? You should really create and post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this.

Comment: Actually, assuming `worldSizeXSlider` is a `Slider`, [`getValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Slider.html#getValue--) returns a primitive `double` and so cannot be `null`. So `worldSizeXSlider` is `null`, i.e. it is not properly initialized. Please show the declaration and the relevant FXML.

Comment: In addition to not providing the annotation (as in the duplicate question), you have the `fx:id` wrong. It must match the field name `worldSizeXSlider`.

Comment: omg thanks. that lowercase threw me off